# recursive search of file with specific extension

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to get count of all the file which ends with particular extension (which user will pass) with the path. We have sub folders as well so search has to be recursive.
Below is what i am trying but it is throwing error. Please suggest where is the gap.
If i remove `if file.endswith(extension):` line then it gives count of all files (which includes files with all extension)

```
import os, sys

def fileCount(path, extension):
    count = 0
    for root, dirs, file in os.walk(path):
        if file.endswith(extension):
            count += len(file)
    return count

print fileCount('/home/export/JobDefinition', '.car')
```

Below is the output:

```
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    print fileCount('/home/export/JobDefinition', '.car')
  File "test.py", line 6, in fileCount
    if file.endswith(extension):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the sum after filtering all the files:

```
def fileCount(path, extension):
    count = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        count += sum(f.endswith(extension) for f in files)
    return count
```

`files` returns a list of files so `sum(f.endswith(extension) for f in files)` will give you the count of all the files ending with the given extension.

Or just return the sum of all:

```
def fileCount(path, extension):
  return sum(f.endswith(extension) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path) for f in files)
```

Comment: excellent answer and as always very elegant ... you could also use `len` (but I like the sum solution :P)

Comment: I get it down to one line ;)

Comment: @JoranBeasley, thanks, yep  len would work fine but the gen exp avoids needing to build a list, probably makes no real difference unless the list was huge.

Comment: @heinst, yes, you could use just return `sum(...`

Answer (score 1):

`os.walk()` is used to iterate through file**S**.

You have to loop through the file**S**, which are returned as a `list`.

```
def fileCount(path, extension):
    count = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(extension):
                count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: I already tried this and it gives me 3333 as count which is way to much. I guess it is giving me all character counts for all files.

Comment: @ankitpandey I edited my answer: maybe should you use `count += 1` instead, that seems logical.

Answer (score 1):

`os.walk()` returns a tuple like - `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)` . Where `filenames` is the list of all files in the directory , its a `list`.

You will need to iterate over the files, rather than using `file.endswith`

Example -

```
import os, sys

def fileCount(path, extension):
    count = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(extension):
                count += 1
    return count

print fileCount('/home/export/JobDefinition', '.car')
```

Comment: I already tried this and it gives me 3333 as count which is way to much. I guess it is giving me all character counts for all files.

Comment: Edited the answer, we needed to add `1` to count for each file found with extension, instead of `len(files)` .

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one liner alternative:

```
import os

def fileCount(path, extension):
    return sum([1 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path) for file in files if file.endswith(extension)])

print fileCount('/home/export/JobDefinition', '.car')
```

Comment: I dont think this is quite what you want ... I suspect you will get much bigger values than you expect

Comment: @JoranBeasley I tested it against the full code and returns the same number

Comment: yeah thats cause the original code is also wrong ... this is the sum of the lengths of the filename strings that match the search (not the number of matches)

Comment: I already tried this and it gives me 3333 as count which is way to much. I guess it is giving me all character counts for all files.

Comment: alright now I can give you an upvote :P ... you ofc could just put the boolean test into the list instead of filtering it :P

Answer (score 0):

The third return value of `os.walk` is a list of file names.